# Could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.reportviewer.common (VS2022)

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

68

I am trying to use the report viewer in . However, when my page containing the report viewer is loaded, it shows the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

I tried downloading many versions but it didn't work